# PHP sniff out Safari Desktop version

Tags: php, safari, cross-browser, user-agent

Super quick one, I know that browser sniffing is frowned upon but I need to (using PHP) detect Desktop version Safari only, cannot seem to find specifically this combination on Google, or SO for that matter.

I know how to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but don't know which bit to look for for Mac OSX/Windows 7/8.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Is there some particular feature or bug that you're trying to deal with?

Comment: i know how to do it in css...not sure if that helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User Agent string for Safari on the Mac will be something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.13+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2
```

on Windows you will find something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; tr-TR) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
```